AJAX Posts Reverse Order After Refresh the Page When Multiple Posts are Created in the Same Minute from Same User
I'm working on a social network project using Django for the backend and JavaScript for the frontend. Users can post new content, and the global feed is updated both dynamically via Ajax and by refreshing the page.
Everything works fine, except when a user creates multiple posts within the same minute. Initially, the newest post is displayed at the top, but when I refresh the page, the order of posts gets reversed for that specific user, where older posts appear above newer ones.
I'm using the created_at field (with DateTimeField) to order the posts. Here's a snippet of the key code that handles fetching the global stream and updating the DOM:
function updateStream(posts) {
    const postContainer = document.querySelector('#post-list');

    posts.forEach(post => {
        let postElement = document.getElementById(`id_post_div_${post.post_id}`);

        if (!postElement) {
            postElement = document.createElement('div');
            postElement.id = `id_post_div_${post.post_id}`;
            postElement.className = 'post';
            postElement.innerHTML = `
                <p>
                    <strong><a href="/profile/${post.author_username}" id="id_post_profile_${post.post_id}" class="post-profile">
                        ${post.author}</a></strong>: 
                    <span id="id_post_text_${post.post_id}" class="post-txt">${sanitize(post.content)}</span>
                    <span id="id_post_date_time_${post.post_id}" class="post-date-time">${formatDate(post.created_at)}</span>
                </p>
                <div class="comments" id="comments_${post.post_id}"></div>
                <div id="id_comment_input_div_${post.post_id}" class="add-comment">
                    <input type="text" id="id_comment_input_text_${post.post_id}" placeholder="Add a comment" />
                    <button id="id_comment_button_${post.post_id}" onclick="addComment(${post.post_id})">Submit</button>
                </div>
            `;

            // Add new post to the correct position
            postContainer.appendChild(postElement);
        }
    });
}

What I’ve Tried:
Adding a fallback to sort by post_id when posts have the same created_at, but it didn’t seem to fix the issue completely.
My Question: How can I ensure that new posts are always displayed at the top, even when multiple posts are created within the same minute?
Any suggestions or guidance on the proper way to handle this would be greatly appreciated!
Update based on the comments:
@David and @Jaromanda X
, thank you for your responses!
You're right—my question mainly focused on the frontend side, and I didn't provide enough detail about the backend sorting logic. I'll clarify that below:
On the backend (Django), I’m using the created_at field (which is a DateTimeField with auto-generated timestamps) to order the posts. Here’s a simplified version of how I’m retrieving and ordering the posts from the database in my view:
def get_global_stream(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
    response = [{"post_id": post.id, "content": post.content, "created_at": post.created_at, "author": post.author.username, "comments": [...] } for post in posts]
    return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)

I use order_by('-created_at') to order the posts in descending order (newest first). The created_at field does contain seconds, but I don't know why it seems doesn't work.

"I'm using the created_at field (with DateTimeField) to order the posts." - I don't see where that's happening in the code shown.  Also, what values are in that field?  If it's a timestamp, does it not contain seconds (and milliseconds)?  An operation which fetches records from data and orders them by a date/time field in that data seems like a fairly straightforward thing, it's not clear why yours isn't sorting as expected.  But I imagine diagnosing it would involve examining that sorting logic, not the displaying logic.

you forgot the code that handles fetching the global stream

If your specific debugging observation is that Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_at') returns data in an unexpected order, you'll want to focus on that.  When you debug, what is the observed runtime value of posts after that operation?
